# JD Edwards EntrepriseOne : Unable to locate security servera

Tags: jdeveloper, jde, jdedwards

I have follow all the steps to install JDE , but i got this error :

```
Failed to communicate with security server: Unable to locate security server
JD Edwards EntrepriseOne could not sign you on.Make sur your User ID is correct and retype your password.
```

This the Log file of JDE :

```
2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:41:52.327000  jdb_ctl.c4196
    Starting OneWorld

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:42:01.822000  JDETOOLS.c3065
    LIB0000569 - WARNING!!! [SECURITY][Password] Password not encrypted in the INI

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:01.862000  jdeksec.c786
    INITIALIZING SECURITY SERVER KERNEL

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:01.862001  jdeksec.c803
    WARNING - failed to find site keys in JDE.INI

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:01.862002  JDETOOLS.c3065
    LIB0000569 - WARNING!!! [SECURITY][Password] Password not encrypted in the INI

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:01.902000  netpub.c999
    JDENet already initialized

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:01.902001  jdb_ctl.c3121
    Net init failed or not initialized

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:01.972000  JDETOOLS.c3065
    LIB0000569 - WARNING!!! [SECURITY][Password] Password not encrypted in the INI

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.704000  jdb_drvm.c478
    JDB9900160 - Failed to load driver library jdboci121.DLL

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.704001  jdb_omp1.c1928
    JDB9900254 - Failed to initialize driver.

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.704002  JTP_CM.c209
    JDB9909002 - Could not init connect.

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.704003  JTP_TM.c1140
    JDB9909100 - Get connect info failed: Transaction ID =

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.704004  jdb_rq1.c2458
    JDB3100013 - Failed to get connectinfo

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.704005  jdb_omp1.c3369
    JDB9900257 - Failed to open F986101

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.834000  jdb_drvm.c478
    JDB9900160 - Failed to load driver library jdboci121.DLL

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.834001  jdb_omp1.c1928
    JDB9900254 - Failed to initialize driver.

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.834002  JTP_CM.c209
    JDB9909002 - Could not init connect.

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.834003  JTP_TM.c1140
    JDB9909100 - Get connect info failed: Transaction ID =

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.834004  jdb_rq1.c2458
    JDB3100013 - Failed to get connectinfo

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.834005  jdb_omp1.c1220
    JDB9900240 - Failed to open F986101

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.834006  jdb_cach.c1369
    JDB9900009 - Failed to load ObjectMap Cache

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.834007  jdb_cach.c1386
    Unable to load primary Object Configuration Manager - switching to secondary

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844000  jdb_omp1.c651
    JDB9900247 - Failed to find F98611 System Local in cache

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844001  jdb_rq1.c2023
    JDB3100011 - Failed to get location of table F986101 for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844002  jdb_omp1.c3369
    JDB9900257 - Failed to open F986101

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844003  jdb_omp1.c651
    JDB9900247 - Failed to find F98611 System Local in cache

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844004  jdb_rq1.c2023
    JDB3100011 - Failed to get location of table F986101 for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844005  jdb_omp1.c1220
    JDB9900240 - Failed to open F986101

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844006  jdb_cach.c1369
    JDB9900009 - Failed to load ObjectMap Cache

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844007  jdb_omp1.c629
    JDB9900246 - Failed to find existence of default OMAP for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844008  jdb_rq1.c2023
    JDB3100011 - Failed to get location of table F00921 for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844009  jdecgsc.c201
    MSC0000028 - Could not load F00921 cache

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844010  jdb_rq1.c3061
    JDB2700019 - Failed to get data source for the table

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844011  jdb_omp1.c629
    JDB9900246 - Failed to find existence of default OMAP for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844012  jdb_rq1.c2023
    JDB3100011 - Failed to get location of table F00941 for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844013  jdb_ctl.c819
    JDB9900408 - Failed to get package release level

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844014  jdb_ctl.c4439
    JDB1100016 - Failed to load Environment - DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844015  jdb_omp1.c629
    JDB9900246 - Failed to find existence of default OMAP for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844016  jdb_rq1.c2023
    JDB3100011 - Failed to get location of table F00941 for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844017  jdb_omp1.c629
    JDB9900246 - Failed to find existence of default OMAP for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844018  jdb_rq1.c2023
    JDB3100011 - Failed to get location of table F00942 for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844019  SpecUtil.c5156
    JDESPEC0000051 - Unable to open F00942 to load metadata cache.  Fatal Error.

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844020  SpecUtil.c5195
    JDESPEC0000052 - Unable to select all records from F00942 to load metadata cache.  Fatal Error.

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.844021  SpecUtil.c5068
    Metadata release cache handle destroyed before it could be used.  System probably being shut down.  Returning failure.

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854000  SpecOpen.c1845
    JDESPEC0000059 - Unable to determine spec release level of the data source DEMO.  Cannot determine metadata format version of this path code.  Cannot acccess metadata (specs)! Fatal Error.

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854001  SpecOpen.c2633
    jdeSpecOpenLocal completed in error - JDESPECRESULT_FAILED.

1992/2944 UNKNOWN                               Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854002  evtcache.c890
    isNewRTESystemEnabled - DDTABL spec handle cannot be accessed.

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854003  jdb_omp1.c629
    JDB9900246 - Failed to find existence of default OMAP for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854004  jdb_rq1.c2023
    JDB3100011 - Failed to get location of table F00942 for environment DEMO920

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854005  SpecUtil.c5156
    JDESPEC0000051 - Unable to open F00942 to load metadata cache.  Fatal Error.

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854006  SpecUtil.c5195
    JDESPEC0000052 - Unable to select all records from F00942 to load metadata cache.  Fatal Error.

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854007  SpecUtil.c5068
    Metadata release cache handle destroyed before it could be used.  System probably being shut down.  Returning failure.

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854008  SpecOpen.c1845
    JDESPEC0000059 - Unable to determine spec release level of the data source DEMO.  Cannot determine metadata format version of this path code.  Cannot acccess metadata (specs)! Fatal Error.

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.854009  SpecOpen.c2633
    jdeSpecOpenLocal completed in error - JDESPECRESULT_FAILED.

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.864000  secutil.c422
    Failed to init security bootstrap environment using user=DEMO, env=DEMO920, role=*ALL

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.864001  jdeksec.c3864
    Failed to init Env

1992/2944 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject            Thu Jun 02 09:42:02.864002  netflow.c1219
    Dispatch Function '_JDEK_DispatchSecurity@28' returned failure on eNetDispatchInit

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:21.839000  jdecsec.c2219
    JDENET Error = eTimeOut

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:46.502000  jdecsec.c2706
    Failed to communicate with security server: Unable to locate Security Server

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:47.990000  jdecsec.c264
    Failed to validate user DEMO by password

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:47.990001  jdb_ctl.c4902
    JDB1100018 - Failed to get past Security check

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:49.048000  msc_signon.cpp227
    ValidateUser failed from SignOn

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.545000  jdb_ctl.c4306
    JDB1100012 - Failed to validate Sign on

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.547000  SpecUtil.c5156
    JDESPEC0000051 - Unable to open F00942 to load metadata cache.  Fatal Error.

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.547001  SpecUtil.c5195
    JDESPEC0000052 - Unable to select all records from F00942 to load metadata cache.  Fatal Error.

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.548000  SpecUtil.c5068
    Metadata release cache handle destroyed before it could be used.  System probably being shut down.  Returning failure.

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.548001  SpecOpen.c1845
    JDESPEC0000059 - Unable to determine spec release level of the data source DEMO.  Cannot determine metadata format version of this path code.  Cannot acccess metadata (specs)! Fatal Error.

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.548002  SpecOpen.c2633
    jdeSpecOpenLocal completed in error - JDESPECRESULT_FAILED.

2424/960 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.549000  evtcache.c890
    isNewRTESystemEnabled - DDTABL spec handle cannot be accessed.

2424/960 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject         Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.550000  SpecUtil.c5156
    JDESPEC0000051 - Unable to open F00942 to load metadata cache.  Fatal Error.

2424/960 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject         Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.550001  SpecUtil.c5195
    JDESPEC0000052 - Unable to select all records from F00942 to load metadata cache.  Fatal Error.

2424/960 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject         Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.550002  SpecUtil.c5068
    Metadata release cache handle destroyed before it could be used.  System probably being shut down.  Returning failure.

2424/960 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject         Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.551000  SpecOpen.c1845
    JDESPEC0000059 - Unable to determine spec release level of the data source DEMO.  Cannot determine metadata format version of this path code.  Cannot acccess metadata (specs)! Fatal Error.

2424/960 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject         Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.551001  SpecOpen.c2633
    jdeSpecOpenLocal completed in error - JDESPECRESULT_FAILED.

2424/960 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject         Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.578000  jdb_ctl.c1364
    JDB4100001 - Failed to validate Env handle

2424/960 WRK:Starting jdeCallObject         Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.728000  jdb_ctl.c10594
    JDB1200017 - Exiting JDB_GetLocalClientEnv with NULL hEnv.

1992/636 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.900000  netpub.c3488
    Info:Net program ended(JDENET_RunNet), pid = 1992, JDENETError = 0

1992/636 MAIN_THREAD                        Thu Jun 02 09:43:51.902000  IPCMISC.C299
    API ipcSawUnregisterProcV1 : process 1992 unregistered in entry 0
```

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699139/unable-to-connecte-with-security-server-jd-edwards-entrepriseone) question, please see answer

Answer (score 0):

Since your Enterprise Server is your Security Server, verify that the JDE services are running.  If they are not, start them.  If they are then stop and restart them.

If this fails after the restart, find the Security Kernel and check the logs.

Since this sounds like a new install, you can edit your JDE.ini file and set the Security Server to *NONE for your Full Client.  Try logging in again.  If you are successful then, most likely there is an issue with your System ID and password.  Verify that the System ID is not disabled or that the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Enterprise server defined as security server in JDE.INI located under /system/bin32 folder on enterprise server (Windows) have correct server name defined under security server section, and ODBC connection must be created (careful as JDE Enterprise server follows 32bit (now it is coming with 64bit too), however I am assuming this server as 32 bit JDE only, so odbc connection must be created using correct odbcad32 (normally in /system/syswow64) location.

Along with that , you can also minimize warning message of site key with enabling this feature (https://docs.oracle.com/en/applications/jd-edwards/unix-linux/9.2/eouuo/generate-site-key.html).

regards,
Brajesh