# Unable to connecte with security server JD Edwards EntrepriseOne

Tags: jdeveloper, jde, jdedwards

its almost 3 days that i got this error :

```
Unable to locate security server.
Failed to communicate with security server
JD Edwards EntrepriseOne could not sign you on.
```

thanks for your help ;

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurs on JDE fat client when database client was configured incorrectly. For example when TNSNAMES.ORA doesn't have correct entry for JDE database.
Please check [oracle support document](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1634546.1) regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about your JDE.INI and the security server is correct
try restarting the JDE E920 Network process